Do indexer bots set navigator.webdriver property to true?

The webdriver read-only property of the navigator interface indicates whether the user agent is controlled by automation.

Source
I couldn't find anywhere if it includes indexing crawlers such as Googlebot. Does anyone know for sure?

Short answer - It does not include indexing crawlers (and has nothing to do with them)
I think you are entirely misunderstanding what is being said in that link - the context for that link appears to be WEB BROWSER interactions - which has nothing to do with web servers or bots.
The question doesn't make a lot of sense because when a Bot is talking to a web server it has nothing to do with a web client (and a bot knows its a bot, and the server doesn't care - and does not get this information).
If you want to tell if a reputable crawler is legitimate, you would do so by looking at the URL and cross checking the IP against the IP ranges used by that bot.  (Its also worth noting that most reputable bots identify themselves as bots, not Mozilla clients)
FWIW, The Webdriver is " WebDriver is a remote control interface that enables introspection and control of user agents. It provides a platform- and language-neutral wire protocol as a way for out-of-process programs to remotely instruct the behavior of web browsers.
Provided is a *set of interfaces to discover and manipulate DOM elements in web documents and to control the behavior of a user agent. It is primarily intended to allow web authors to write tests that automate a user agent from a separate controlling process, but may also be used in such a way as to allow in-browser scripts to control a — possibly separate — browser. "
(ref: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-webdriver, bolding mine)
It then goes on to explain that the specification is derived from the Selenium WebDriver browser automation framework.   Selenium is a way of pretending to be a browser for the purpose of checking how browsers see and work with a website.    None of this has anything to do with bots.
